# Find basis of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I don't know how to create basis of V1 and V2. If I want to prove M1^2=M1, do I need to find matrix representation of M1 first?
Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, it's enough to show that for any $x$:
$$
M_1(M_1(x)) = M_1(x)
$$
In particular, note that (in the notation of the question) $M_1(x_1 + x_2) = x_1 + 0$.